# Classic ASP: encoding text outside tags with regex

Tags: regex, encoding, asp-classic

I'm in the need of a function that could process a string and replace textual parts with html encoded ones:

Sample 1

```
Input: "<span>Total amount:<br>€ 50,00</span>"
Output: "<span>Total amount:<br>&euro; 50,00</span>"
```

Sample 2

```
Input: "<span>When threshold > x<br>act as described below:</span>"
Output: "<span>When threshold &gt; x<br>act as described below:</span>"
```

These are simplified cases of course, and yes, I know I could do that by a series of replace on each specific char I need to encode, but I'd rather have a function that can recognize and skip HTML tags using Regex and perform a Server.HTMLEncode on the textual part of the input string. 
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'd say you'll probably find it simpler to focus on where the text and markup are combined and apply encoding to the values then. `"<span>" & Server.HTMLEncode("€ 50,00") & "</span>"`

Comment: Is your HTML mixed in to the text you need to process?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this.  Why don't you just pass the innerHTML into your parser using javascript and have Javascript create your span tag?  Then you can encode the entire thing.  I'd be worried that the encoding here won't have any added security for your application if that's what you are trying to do.

Comment: This function will run on server side, the reported samples aren't giving the idea of the texts' real complexity this function will have to parse. Basically I have a DB with 10K product descriptions that include tags like <br>, <i>, <strong> as formatting, but also include unencoded special characters like àèìòùé€ (Italian language) in text parts. A the moment I need to encode the texts becouse we're experiencing a lot of problems with utf-8 encoding, needed to exchange data with an ERP platform we're connecting to the exhisiting application. Hope it's a little bit more clear now. Thank you.